# ASP.NET MVC Identity database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

So I have created a database and built some things on top. Can I alter the Account modelview and controller so all Identity information adds to my database instead of the default?

Comment: Which database is used is simply a matter of setting the connection string.

Comment: Thanks, So seeing as I haven't used it yet, If I remove the default string -  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data  and only have  <add name="WOMSEntities" connectionString=", surely I need to stipulate which database to use in the controllers etc?

Comment: You can just keep the name as "DefaultConnection" and just change the connectionString attribute to your new connection string. If you change the name to "WOMSEntities", you'll have to change the DbContext constructor to use the new connection string name.

Comment: Oh wow that's cool. Then it will script and add relevant tables to my DB? As I said I built this database first and was under the impression that identity was difficult/impossible to implement this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, you have an `ApplicationDbContext` defined as such:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

To change the connection string, either:

1. Change the properties of the existing `DefaultConnection` connection string in your `web.config`
2. Add a new connection string in your web.config, and change the `ApplicationDbContext` constructor to pass in the new name.

Comment: Hi Brendan. Thanks for this. How are the database tables generated etc? When Identity features are first used? Will I have to add these myself? Thanks

Comment: The tables are created in the database via code-fist migrations.  You shouldn't need to create them yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So if I configure it as you stated and register an duff account it will all be generated?

Comment: how come I now have: private WOMSEntities db = new WOMSEntities(); Error 2 The type or namespace name 'WOMSEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Has the db altered the WOMSEntities db somehow?

Comment: Show the updates to the ApplicationDbContext class that you made.  Also, where in the code is this error happening?

Comment: I Just pointed <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString to the same place <add name="WOMSEntities" connectionString= points too. All the errors are within the controllers. Also If i make new controllers it doesn't see the db tables?

Comment: You might need to post some code.  Just changing the connection string should not have caused the compile errors you are mentioning.

Comment: I updated the model too. As in model1.edmx - Update model from db